# Creating a Matrix whose columnwise entries are a copy of a given row vector

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-algebra

Afternoon there.  I have a quick question.  Right now I have an arbitrary sized data matrix that I am creating using numpy.  This particular matrix is entirely numerical values-and I'd like to compute the matrix of the column means.  That is-for column j in this mean matrix, the a_ij entry should have the associated column mean as its entry.  Here's an example

Simple Data matrix

```
[1,3,4;1,4,4;1,5,2]
```

meanmatrix:

```
[1,3,2;1,3,2;1,3,2]
```

I have an idea on how I should go about this but I'm running into some issues.  Here's the overview /my approach

```
def data matrix
#create empty array
 mean_matrix=[]
#for i in len (data matrix)

#create mean vector using np.mean
 mean=np.mean(data matrix)
#append such vector to empty list
 np.append(mean_matrix, mean)
#return
```

I'm not sure if I should be using the append function-specifically creating an empty array within the for loop here, appending the empty matrix with the result of a prior iteration in the loop or creating the of the mean matrix entries directly

much thanks

Comment: You can use `np.repeat(np.mean(data, axis=0, keepdims=True), len(data), axis=0)`

Comment: works great!  thanks.  any idea on how it works syntacticly(?) or should i open the variable explorer and do some digging?

Comment: Well, obviously I know how it works ;-) `mean` computes the mean along axis 0, keeping this axis a singleton, so the intermediate has shape (1, data.shape[1]). `repeat` then takes this and repeats the whole thing len(data) times along axis 0, so the original shape is restored.

Comment: ooops- I meant the logic haha.  I understand the function at face :D

thanks again so much-this helped a ton ahha.  Now I don't have to copy and paste a command 50 thousand times in my csv lawl.